# Can Visual Studio 2010 Express automatically register 64-bit DLLs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com

I've been following the beginner's tutorial for building SW Addins at [Angel Six](http://www.angelsix.com/cms/products/tutorials/64-solidworks/67-creating-a-solidworks-add-in-from-scratch).  I'm trying to get Visual Studio to automatically register the DLL, but I'm using 64 bit SolidWorks on a 64 bit machine, and it doesn't seem to want to do it automatically.  I've performed the two steps described in the tutorial (Make Assembly COM-Visible and Register for COM Interop).

When I build, I don't get errors of any kind, it's just that when I check the registry with regedit I don't see my addin in SOFTWARE/SolidWorks/Addins , nor can I seem to find it anywhere (e.g. I looked under HKEY_CURRENT_USER in addition to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

Like I said, I am curious if Visual Studio can automatically register 64 bit DLLs; I went through the manual registration process using 64-bit regasm.exe, and that worked just fine.

I'm running VS 2010 Express on a Windows 7 Machine with SolidWorks 2012 x64 Student Edition installed.  Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to trace the registration.  [ComVisible] assemblies normally need much more registration, do check with Solidworks what the requirements are.

Comment: Using the 64-bit version of regasm.exe definitely worked.  In his tutorial, this guy sets up a way of making visual studio do the registration automatically... is there a way to do that with 64 bit dlls?

Comment: No, the "Register for COM interop" option only works for 32-bit COM servers.  You could run Regasm.exe in a post build event, assuming Express supports them.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  You could make that the, uh, answer.  :)

Comment: Go ahead an post your own answer and accept it.  I don't know enough about the Express edition nor Solidworks to know if my answer would be accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Register for COM interop" option in Visual Studio 2010 Express only works for 32-bit COM servers (as mentioned by Hans Passat above).  To get the DLL to register appropriately with COM for SolidWorks, you can run cmd AS ADMINISTRATOR, then do the following

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
regasm.exe "C:\full\path\to\your.dll" /codebase
```

This is possible to run as a post-build action in VS 2010 express, just go to the properties of your project, click the build tab, and add those two lines above to any commands you may already have.

The plugin should then successfully register and work with 64-bit SolidWorks.